# How can I bind a key to "exit copy-mode" in tmux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I was trying to find a command for "leaving copy-mode" from [this page](http://hyperpolyglot.org/multiplexers), but it seems only the key binding <kbd>prefix+q</kbd> exists for this function; i.e., I can't find the associated `:command`-style command.

Does this mean it is impossible to bind another key to "leave copy-mode"? I'd like to bind the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Copy mode uses its own set of commands, separate from `tmux` itself. Use `send-keys -X` to "type" commands in copy mode, as demonstrated by the default binding for exiting copy mode:

```
bind-key    -T copy-mode    q                 send-keys -X cancel
```

Note that Escape is already bound to the same command, at least in `tmux` 2.7.

```
% tmux list-keys | grep "send-keys -X cancel"
bind-key    -T copy-mode    C-c               send-keys -X cancel
bind-key    -T copy-mode    Escape            send-keys -X cancel
bind-key    -T copy-mode    q                 send-keys -X cancel
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi C-c               send-keys -X cancel
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi q                 send-keys -X cancel
```

The page you were referring to is not a comprehensive list of `tmux` commands, but rather a comparison of how to accomplish some common tasks in different terminal multiplexers.

Comment: Thanks! Is this also possible in older versions of TMUX (i.e., versions where the `-t` flag is used instead of the `-T` flag?). I noticed the `-X` option is critical for sending the given command to copy-mode, so perhaps not?

Comment: You'd have to consult your man page; I don't have an older version available to check if it may have been different.

Comment: Nevermind! I noticed the answer to this question already lay in my `.tmux.conf`; I just had been copying-pasting stuff and not understanding what was going on. To replicate this behavior before tmux version 2.4, use `bind -t vi-copy Escape cancel`.

Comment: The `tmux list-keys ...` was the most useful for me. ... teaching me how to fish instead of feeding me fish.  Thank you!